# textbox inside bottomsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a bottomsheet which looks like below

[image: this]

It has a text box inside it when I cliked on that I am getting something like
 [image: below]

my text box is completely covered by the keyboard. 
is there any way to solve this?

below is code

```
Widget buildSupportingWidget(
      Map<String, Object> items, StateSetter setState) {
    if (items['type'] == "string") {
      dispName = items['displayName'];
      return Container(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 27.0,
                vertical: 16.0,
              ),
              child: new TextFormField(
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Enter value",
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: filterTextFieldData,
              )));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I am calling above widget inside the bottomshhet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Last week I faced same issue I solved it by create stateful bottom sheet and add Container with height last widget of Column

Open bottom sheet

```
 InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (context) {
                  return ModalBottomSheet(
                    
                      );
                });
          })
```

Stateful bottom sheet

```
    class ModalBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
 

      @override
     _ModalBottomSheetState createState() => _ModalBottomSheetState();
    }

     class _ModalBottomSheetState extends State<ModalBottomSheet>
      with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

      @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
          child: Column( 
           children: <Widget>[
            Widgets(),
            Container(
                height:  keyboardHeight ,
              )
          ]
            )
          )
        ],
      );
     }

    }
```

also [Keyboard Visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) package help me to check keyboard open or not