# How do I change the state of modalBottomSheet depending on the List which comes from server in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I have a modalBottomSheet which shows two CupertinoPickers, one is a date picker and the other is an hour picker. I want to reach this effect: when date is changed in the picker, I send a request to server to check if there are available hours on that date, if yes, the picker on the right should show only those hours which are available, if there are no available hours, it should show a text. I tried StatefulBuilder to setState of modalBottomSheet, but as soon the list becomes empty, it doesn't fill up, and there are shown hours not of the date I am at right now, but the previous one.

```
  showUniversalPicker() {
    _selectedTime = 'ВСЕ';
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              StateSetter setSheetState,
            ) {
              return Container(
                height: 300,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CupertinoButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Отменить',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            CupertinoButton(
                              child: Text(
                                'Подтвердить',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _date = DateTime(
                                    _selectedDate.year,
                                    _selectedDate.month,
                                    _selectedDate.day,
                                    _selectedTime == 'ВСЕ'
                                        ? 00
                                        : int.parse(_selectedTime),
                                  );
                                });
                                print(_selectedTime);
                                _calendarController.setSelectedDay(_date);
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ChooseVideo(
                                      date: _date,
                                      wholeDay:
                                          _selectedTime == "ВСЕ" ? true : false,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      child: Flex(
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 8,
                            child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                              // minuteInterval: 1,
                              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                              initialDateTime: _date,
                              onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime) {
                                // setState(() {
                                //   setModalSheetState = setSheetState;
                                // });
                                // debugger();
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedDate = dateTime;
                                });
                                // _timeList.clear();
                                // setSheetState(() {
                                //   _timeList.add("ВСЕ");
                                //   getHours();
                                //   for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                                //     if (_hours.contains(
                                //         i.toString().padLeft(2, '0'))) {
                                //       _timeList.add(
                                //         i.toString().padLeft(2, '0'),
                                //       );
                                //     }
                                //   }
                                // });
                                // setTimeList();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: CupertinoPicker(
                                itemExtent: 38,
                                magnification: 0.95,
                                useMagnifier: true,
                                // looping: true,
                                onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedTime = _timeList[index];
                                  });
                                },
                                children: _timeList
                                    .map(
                                      (item) => Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          item,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    .toList()),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

This is the part of the code I use right now.

Comment: I think you need to create a state full bottom sheet widget.

Comment: How do I do that, I can't seem to find anything similar in docs or in google

Comment: State full bottom sheet example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709903/textbox-inside-bottomsheet-in-flutter/58711181#58711181