# How to move TextField up when keyboard appears?

Tags: flutter, dart

Textfield inside bottom sheet gets hidden when keyboard pops up to type inside textfield in flutter. How to move TextField up when keyboard appears?

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.west,
            size: 30,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          Icon(
            Icons.filter,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          VideoCardWidget(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            // gradient: LinearGradient(
                            //   colors: [Color(0xFF6589AB), Colors.white],
                            //   begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                            //   end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            // ),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(15),
                                  ),
                                  child: Card(
                                    elevation: 10,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          fillColor: Color(0xFFf5f5f5),
                                          filled: true,
                                          hintText: 'Ask your Doubts',
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                        maxLines: 15,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                                    child: TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 40.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Send',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      style: ButtonStyle(
                                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                            RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                          Color(0xFF003b73),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Color(0xFF003b73),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Ask Your Doubt',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Color(0xFF003b73),
                  ),
                ),
                // onPressed: _openQuizBottomSheet,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Quiz',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Color(0xFF003b73),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.push(
                  //   context,
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) {
                  //       return KeyNoteScreen();
                  //     },
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Key Notes',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Use `singleChildScrollView`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709903/textbox-inside-bottomsheet-in-flutter/58711181#58711181

Answer (score 1):

in your case you need to set `isScrollControlled` in your `showModalBottomSheet` as follows:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
```

but In general, you can have to approaches:

1. use `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to avoid the overflow:

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, // this avoids the overflow error
// in flutter 2.0 or upper versions, use resizeToAvoidBottomInset  instead
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField Animation Demo'),
      ),
```

2. or wrap your whole widget by `SingleChildScrollView`. However, as you returning `column`, first you need to wrap it by suitable container size. for example set height of this container based on the screen size.

Comment: The named parameter 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding' isn't defined in flutter 2.0

Comment: I did not know that, however, I have provided 3 solutions, he can use two others.

Comment: Yeah it is resizeToAvoidBottomInset

Comment: great, thank you! I will update my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need Wrap Column with SingleChildScrollView